# RxJava Backpressure and number of calls to producer

Tags: rx-java, producer, backpressure

I am trying to create infinity-scroll in my Android application using backpressure in rx Java. I want it to call external service only requested number of times (after calling `request(1)`). But after using flatmap every `subscribe` loads 16 pages.

below my code with expected results. Almost every test fail because of first request (with n=16)

```java
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import rx.Observable;
import rx.observers.TestSubscriber;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import static java.util.Collections.emptyList;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static rx.internal.util.UtilityFunctions.identity;

public class ServiceObservablesTest {


    public static <T> Observable<List<T>> create(DataProvider<T> dataProvider) {
        Observable<Observable<List<T>>> metaObservalble = Observable.create(subscriber -> {
            AtomicInteger pageNumber = new AtomicInteger();
            subscriber.setProducer(n -> {
                // at subscribe rxJava makes request for 16 elements - probably because of flatMap
                // after first request with 16 elements everything seems to work fine even if i ignore the 'n' param

                Observable<List<T>> page = dataProvider.requestPage(pageNumber.getAndIncrement());
                subscriber.onNext(page);

            });
        });
        return metaObservalble.flatMap(identity()).takeWhile(page -> !page.isEmpty());
    }

    public interface DataProvider<T> {
        Observable<List<T>> requestPage(int page);
    }


    private DataProvider provider;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        provider = Mockito.mock(DataProvider.class);
        List<Object> list = Arrays.asList(new Object());
        when(provider.requestPage(anyInt())).thenReturn(Observable.just(list));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldRequestOnlyFirstPageOnSubscribe() {
        //given

        TestSubscriber<List<Object>> subscriber = new TestSubscriber<>(1);
        Observable<List<Object>> flightsObservable = create(provider);

        //when
        flightsObservable.subscribe(subscriber);

        //then
        subscriber.assertValueCount(1);
        subscriber.assertNotCompleted();

        verify(provider, times(1)).requestPage(0);
        verify(provider, never()).requestPage(1);
    }


    @Test
    public void shouldRequestNumberOfPagesSpecified() {
        //given

        int requested_pages = 5;
        TestSubscriber<List<Object>> subscriber = new TestSubscriber<>(0);
        Observable<List<Object>> flightsObservable = create(provider);

        //when
        flightsObservable.subscribe(subscriber);
        subscriber.requestMore(requested_pages);

        //then
        subscriber.assertValueCount(requested_pages);
        subscriber.assertNotCompleted();


        for (int i = 0; i < requested_pages; i++) {
            verify(provider, times(1)).requestPage(i);
        }
        verify(provider, never()).requestPage(requested_pages);

    }


    @Test
    public void shouldCompleteAfterRetrievingEmptyResult() {
        //given

        int emptyPage = 2;
        when(provider.requestPage(emptyPage)).thenReturn(Observable.just(emptyList()));

        TestSubscriber<List<Object>> subscriber = new TestSubscriber<>(100);
        Observable<List<Object>> flightsObservable = create(provider);


        //when
        flightsObservable.subscribe(subscriber);

        //then
        subscriber.assertValueCount(emptyPage);
        subscriber.assertCompleted();


        verify(provider, times(1)).requestPage(0); //requested at subscribe
        for (int i = 1; i <= emptyPage; i++) {
            verify(provider, times(1)).requestPage(i);
        }
        verify(provider, never()).requestPage(emptyPage + 1);

    }

    @Test
    public void shouldRequestNextPageWhenRequestedMore() {
        //given

        TestSubscriber<List<Object>> subscriber = new TestSubscriber<>(1);
        Observable<List<Object>> flightsObservable = create(provider);

        //when
        flightsObservable.subscribe(subscriber);
        subscriber.requestMore(1);

        //then
        subscriber.assertValueCount(2);
        verify(provider, times(1)).requestPage(0);
        verify(provider, times(1)).requestPage(1);
        verify(provider, never()).requestPage(2);

        //when
        subscriber.requestMore(1);

        //then
        subscriber.assertValueCount(3);
        subscriber.assertNotCompleted();

        verify(provider, times(1)).requestPage(0);
        verify(provider, times(1)).requestPage(1);
        verify(provider, times(1)).requestPage(2);
        verify(provider, never()).requestPage(3);

    }

    @Test
    public void shouldWorkWithMultipleSubscribers() {

        //given

        TestSubscriber<List<Object>> subscriber1 = new TestSubscriber<>(1);
        TestSubscriber<List<Object>> subscriber2 = new TestSubscriber<>(1);
        Observable<List<Object>> flightsObservable = create(provider);

        //when
        flightsObservable.subscribe(subscriber1);
        flightsObservable.subscribe(subscriber2);

        //then
        subscriber1.assertValueCount(1);
        subscriber2.assertValueCount(1);

        verify(provider, times(2)).requestPage(0);
        verify(provider, never()).requestPage(1);

        //when
        subscriber1.requestMore(1);
        //then
        subscriber1.assertValueCount(2);
        subscriber2.assertValueCount(1);

        verify(provider, times(2)).requestPage(0);
        verify(provider, times(1)).requestPage(1);
        verify(provider, never()).requestPage(2);

        //when
        subscriber2.requestMore(1);
        //then
        subscriber1.assertValueCount(2);
        subscriber2.assertValueCount(2);

        verify(provider, times(2)).requestPage(0);
        verify(provider, times(2)).requestPage(1);
        verify(provider, never()).requestPage(2);
    }

}
```

Comment: Will the `DataProvider.requestPage(int)` schedule work using a thread, future, `observeOn(Scheduler)`, or `subscribeOn(Scheduler)`?

Comment: yes, I am using both `subscribeOn` and `observeOn`

Comment: Your metaObservable implements backpressure incorrectly and it doesn't complete. By default, flatMap/merge subscribes to only 16 Observables at a time and won't move on unless they complete eventually.

Answer (score 3):

Back pressure is intended to negotiate concurrent consumer producer behavior and allow the program author to set strategies for resolving what to do when the rate of data produced exceeds the rate of data consumed.

That said, you'll see that operators that combine observables such as `merge` will give you a requested amount that doesn't correspond with the amount of data you require. The outer observable (an Observable of Observables) will always receive a request for 16 on RxAndroid (128 in RxJava) when merging. Then as it receives inner Observables of List each inner observable will receive a request that is based on the requested amount from the downstream subscriber. If you try to write an `Observable<Observable<T>>` you will be forced to write an `OnSubscribe<Observable<List<T>>>` function that internally manages the merging behavior so that it was an `Observable<List<T>>` instead of `Observable<Observable<List<T>>`. Writing this would force you to subscribe to the observable returned by your data provider to unwrap and onNext the `List<T>`.

I suggest that you instead map screen y-positions into End-Of-Page events then use a scan to convert that into a monotonically increasing number and then concatMap that number into a call to `DataProvider.requestPage()`.

```java
screenYPositions
    .map(this::isUninitializedOrNearEndOfPage)
    .scan(1, (event, pageNumber) -> pageNumber + 1 )
    .concatMap(dataProvider::requestPage)
    .subscribe(testSubscriber);
```

Comment: on Android I believe the default ring buffer size is 16 rather than 128

Comment: Ah that was my theory. Thanks Dave!

Comment: So the merge preloads the data and there is no way to control how many times the producer will be called?

Comment: Merge will call 'producer.request(int)` at a variable rate that depends on the rates the producer onNexts data and the rate that the operator chain below merge consumes data. `observeOn` also has a buffer among other operators all of which use back pressure for filling and draining the buffers.